# How to reset an object in objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a model called calculatorModel. Once the entry has been saved from this model, I want to basically reset all the variables in it to either blank, 0, etc... so that the screen will clear up. What is the best way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you just have a reset method that changes values to the same default as on `init`?

Comment: Be sure to set properties on UI controls to update the "screen".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either reset them each individually, or you can deallocate your entire `calculatorModel` and create a new one.

Comment: I imagine it is just [xxxx dealloc]; ? But how do you do it using ARC?

Comment: If you're using ARC (you probably are), just set it to `nil`.  It will be deallocated when it no longer has any strong pointers to it.  If you're using MRC, you would need to `[xxx release]`.

Comment: You never *ever* call `dealloc` directly!

Comment: Obviously... Arc won't allow it